# ARM Debian (squeeze) USB driver with mismatch 3.3.3 kernel but /lib/modules/2.6.36

Tags: debian, kernel, arm

Hei guys,

my sheevaplug embedded server works fine, but when I wanted to use USB, the device gets not attached to /dev/tty/USB0

lsusb shows correctly:

*Bus 001 Device 002: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port*

an modprobe usbserial raises:
**FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.3.3/modules.dep: No such file or directory**

**in the /lib/modules/ Folder there is instead a 2.6.36-Folder**

uname -r gives 3.3.3

How can I overcome this mismatch?

Can I create a symlink?

I can't flash this embedded device since it is deployed somewhere, only ssh?

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

first I copied the [System.map](http://www.xilka.com/sheeva/3/3.3/3.3.3/sheeva-3.3.3-System.map) to /boot

then executed *depmod -eF /boot/sheeva-3.3.3-System.map 3.3.3*

Since the 3.3.3 folder was missing the kernel folder thus the drivers, the Modules.tar.gz laid already from in my /root dir.

*tar x -C / --overwrite -zf sheeva-3.3.3-Modules.tar.gz*
put them in the right directory and a reboot solved the problem.

All thanks to [BigBear](http://www.newit.co.uk/forum/index.php/topic,3374.0.html) from the newIT UK forum everything worked as it should.